# Use Retrofit to parse text from JSON file in local

Tags: android, json, parsing, retrofit

I have a JSON text file in `/res/raw`. After reading its text content, I would like to use Retrofit to parse JSON text to Object. But it seems Retrofit only accept input from file in server.

Is there anyway to reuse Retrofit's JSON parser module in this case?

Comment: Is there any reason that you didn't use [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)?

Comment: Retrofit isn't the right tool for this.  Use gson https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: Just read the file and pass the contents to Gson.

Comment: Thank you @bbaker : yes I should use Gson instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure Gson instance once and then just use it both for local parsing and for Retrofit via `RestAdapter.Builder.setConverter(new GsonConverter(customGson)`