# Load a locally stored JSON file - Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

I've been using Retrofit for JSON parsing and it works very well with REST APIs.

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://path_to_json_response")
        .setConverter(new GsonConverter(gson))
        .build();
```

Right now, I've a `.json` file stored in my `assets` folder. How can I use Retrofit to load this JSON file. Is there a change to be made in the `setEndpoint` method? If yes, then what exactly would be the change?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26922591/use-retrofit-to-parse-text-from-json-file-in-local

Answer (score 0):

why not read the file from local using FileReader and then store the string in variable and parse by using JSONObject provided in android by default.

Comment: I want to do this through retrofit only.